# How to RewriteRule from teamquadb.php?url=vms to /teamquadb/vms

Tags: php, .htaccess

My `RewriteRule` from `teamquadb.php?url= to teamquadb\___` does not work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^teamquadb\(.*)\$ teamquadb.php?url=$1 [nc]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you add some more information? "not work" may mean many things. Can you edit your question and add examples of what you expect to happen, and what actually happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your slashes are around the wrong way, and your pattern expects a second slash at the end of the URL.

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^teamquadb/([^/]+)/?$ teamquadb.php?url=$1 [nc]
```

Test your rules at https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

**Update**

Expanding on this answer, in response to the OP's comment against it.

To get *teamquadb/vms/1* to route to *teamquadb.php?url=vms&numberq=1*

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^teamquadb/([^/]+)/?$ teamquadb.php?url=$1 [nc]
RewriteRule ^teamquadb/vms/([^/]+)/?$ teamquadb.php?url=vms&numberq=$1 [nc]
```

Test: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=2e96e804-9415-54bf-84d0-062d9b501f68

To get *teamquadb/**[SOMETHING#1]**/**[SOMETHING#2]*** to route to *teamquadb.php?url=**[SOMETHING#1]**&numberq=**[SOMETHING#2]***, we'd use

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^teamquadb/([^/]+)/?$ teamquadb.php?url=$1 [nc]
RewriteRule ^teamquadb/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ teamquadb.php?url=$1&numberq=$2 [nc]
```

Test: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=2e96e804-9415-54bf-84d0-062d9b501f68

Comment: if is teamquadb/vms/1 = teamquadb.php?url=vms&numberq=1
how to write RewriteRule
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^teamquadb/(.*)/?$(.*)/?$ teamquadb.php?url=$1&numberq=$2 [nc]`
my code no work